# How to compress multiple folders, each into its own zip archive and choose destination in linux command line?

Tags: linux, backup, zip

How to compress multiple folders, each into its own zip archive and choose destination.
For example: 
I have mounted device "ssd"
I have a lot of folders :

```
home/user1/folder1
home/user1/folder2
...
home/user1/folderN
```

And I want get:

```
/media/user1/ssd/MyBackUp/folder1.zip
/media/user1/ssd/MyBackUp/folder2.zip
...
/media/user1/ssd/MyBackUp/folderN.zip
```

Comment: Sorry, in real I have not only three folder but a lot of folders

Answer (score 3):

Using **`zip`** utility:

-- changing the current directory to `user1`:

```
cd user1/
```

-- compressing all folders within current directory:

```
for f in */; do zip -rq "/media/user1/ssd/MyBackUp/${f%/}.zip" "$f"; done
```